# Gorilla websocket with google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go, gorilla

I am getting following error when I am running "goapp serve myapp/" from Myproject folder inside src.

> go-app-builder: Failed parsing input: parser: bad import "unsafe" in
>   github.com/gorilla/websocket/client.go from GOPATH

my file structure is some something like this

```
$GOPATH/src
|-github.com/gorilla/websocket
|-MyProject
   |-myapp
      |-app.yaml
      |-mainApp.go (which contain init function and part of app package)
```

Please let me know how to correct this.

on a related subject, I read that google app provide websocket support only in paid app. Is there a way for me to test my website before getting into payment mode? Or is there a better option that google app engine?

Comment: @MellowMarmot - done. thanks.

Comment: For posterity: this was fixed by Gary (the maintainer) after Dheeraj raised the issue: https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/issues/200

Comment: That was a super quick fix, thank you very much for your help. Meanwhile, does GAE do not support websockets? I am try to connect to it but it is always showing "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400"

Comment: It looks like they don't support it on GAE classic: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2535 - Heroku does, and Google's Firebase product may.